# Intervention Image Upload Saved to Database with Folder Name

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I am Try to Upload User Avatar with Intervention Image as below private function

Everything working fine but image name save to database with my specific folder name

eg : user_avatar/image.jpg

Here is My Code Thanks everyone

```
private function storeAvatar($user)
{
    if (request()->hasFile('avatar')) {
        $user->update([
            'avatar' => request()->avatar->store('user_avatar', 'public'),
        ]);
        $avatar = Image::make(public_path('storage/' .$user->avatar))->fit(300, 300);
        $avatar->save();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brjNo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting a file name.

```
$path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs(
    'avatars', $request->user()->id
);
```

As indicated here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-uploads

So your line should be:

```
 $user->update([
            'avatar' => request()->avatar->storeAs('user_avatar', 'filename', 'public'),
        ]);
```

Or something along those lines. You can also use the file name as uploaded by making the filename the same as the original.

```
$filename = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: Thank your sir, I am Beginner , So could you please write full function for me than i can learn from your code